# Checking variable value with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

How can I check a variable value with Jasmine? Imagine for example that I have this function:

```
function myTestFunction(){
   var z = 100;
}
```

How can I test with Jasmine if the value of my variable "z" is 100?

Something like:

```
describe("TEST 1", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        setUpHTMLFixture();                                 
        $('#show').trigger("onmouseover");                      
    });

    it("check if value contains 100", function () {
        expect($(var z)).toEqual("100");            
    });
});
```

Comment: `z` is scoped *inside* the function.  How do you expose the value?

Comment: Yeah, you can't really check that. Do you really need to test it? Think about it, it might be manifesting in a different way that you should be testing instead.